# RSS Reader not displaying selected Cell in WebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, rss, webview

I've been trying to make a simple RSS Reader app following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial).

The tutorial had to be adapted a bit because I'm using Xcode 4.3.2. Everything works, it loads all the RSS feeds fine, but when i click on a article to view it, the detail view controller loads but its completely blank. Ive tried adding a label or a button to the DetailViewController on the storyboard but even these don't appear when it loads. The only thing that is visible is the navigation bar at the top. So my question is what am i doing wrong? I'm sure its a simple setup problem, rather than a problem with the code. The fact i can add any object to the view and there not displayed its almost like a completely different view controller is being loaded. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Heres the code I've been using:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
_webViewController.entry = entry;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_webViewController animated:YES];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_entry.articleUrl];    
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
NSLog(@"The URL is %@",url);


}
```

Because this code was adapted from a older version of Xcode, has it got something to do with the storyboard instead of individual nib files?

Ok _webviewController is set in the RootViewController.h

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {
NSOperationQueue *_queue;
NSArray *_feeds;
NSMutableArray *_allEntries;
DetailViewController *_webViewController;
```

}

```
@property (retain) NSOperationQueue *queue;
@property (retain) NSArray *feeds;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *allEntries;
@property (retain) DetailViewController *webViewController;
```

didselectRowAtIndex is set in RootViewController & viewDidload is set in DetailViewController

Ive allready set up a push segue in the storyboard.

I have now replaced the tableView didSelectRowAtPath method with the one suggested below

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// test segue.identifier if needed
DetailViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
// set properties of viewController based on selection indexPath
RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
viewController.entry = entry;
}
```

Unfortunately even though this seems to work fine, I'm still getting a blank view.

Comment: Here is another reference link for the RSS feed http://bit.ly/HrlAGV

Comment: Lots of possibilities here Neil, Have you implement web view delegate method for check error? Check with NSLOg that data is moving properly in webviewcontroller ? first check with static label.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used NSLog and got the following: The URL is (null) Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x6e3d1b0>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.

1. I don't see a place where you're setting `_webViewController` to anything before you attempt to push it on the navigation controller. This would be why you're seeing the "Application tried to push a nil view controller on target" error, and may be related to why you're seeing a blank view.
2. Are the two methods you've quoted in your question both implemented in the same class? Presumably, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is in your table view controller (RootViewController in the Ray Wenderlich tutorial), and `viewDidLoad` is in the web view controller? If so, please include such information when asking questions. If not, that may be part of your problem.
3. Most importantly, it sounds like you're trying to adapt the tutorial to use storyboards. On the plus side, this means you can do a lot of stuff in IB that you'd have to do in code otherwise. On the downside, this makes the program "flow" between view controllers a lot different, so it's a bit harder to interpret the tutorial.

The main difference when using storyboards is that the storyboard is responsible for creating and pushing/presenting your view controllers. (Having the root view controller keep and reuse an instance of the web view controller was anti-pattern anyway.) Here's how you do things in the storyboard world:

1. Assuming your storyboard already contains your root table view controller embedded in a navigation controller, put your web view controller on the storyboard by dragging a `UIViewController` out of the library and setting its class identity to your `WebViewController`.
2. Control-drag from the prototype cell in your table view to the web view controller, and make it a Push segue:

   [image: drag to create segue]
3. With the above, you can run your app and get from the table view to the web view (with no code -- yay!), but the web view doesn't know what URL to load. So, you'll need to put the following in your table view controller:

   ```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
       // test segue.identifier if needed
       WebViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       // set properties of viewController based on selection indexPath
       RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       viewController.entry = entry;
   }
   ```
4. And then you'll need the web view controller to load the URL in its web view -- the `viewDidLoad` implementation you already have should be good for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help rickster, I've amended my question according to your reply. Unfortunately I'm still getting a blank view.

Comment: Are you getting your "The URL is" log when that blank view appears? If not, I'd guess either a) the `viewDidLoad` which contains it is implemented on the wrong view controller, b) the blank view isn't actually an instance of your WebViewController (or DetailViewController or whatever you're calling the class managing your web view). If you are seeing that log, then the view controller is getting the URL, but there's a problem passing it to the web view. What does `self.WebView` point to at that time?

Comment: Yeah i get the "The URL is (null)" message when the blank view appears. Sorry for being a noob but what do you mean by what does the 'self.webView' point too at the time?

Comment: 1: Getting the "The URL is" log means your (detail) view controller is getting set up, but it being `(null)` means there's something wrong with passing the URL in. Try logging `_entry`. If it's nil, too, I'd guess you've found a problem with my instructions or your `entry` property isn't `strong` (or `retain`).

Comment: 2: It sounds like `self.webView` should be a reference (hooked up via IBOutlet, probably) to a `UIWebView` instance. We know from your "The URL is (null)" log that the problem comes before passing the URL to the web view -- otherwise I'd suggest making sure that self.webView isn't nil when you get to the `self.webView loadRequest...` line (which you can check with another NSLog or a debugger breakpoint).